# Posting to Google Plus stream/wall with PHP

Tags: php, google-plus

Is it now possible to post to Google plus user wall/stream as it's possible with Facebook Api (`'scope' => 'publish_steam'`)?

This [Google Plus Api](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) looks like it's read only.

I have found something called Moments: https://developers.google.com/+/history/api/moments. But I have no idea how run it with php.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The History API is currently in developer preview. Before trying to use it, make sure you have signed up. You may also want to go through the sample application to get an idea for what it does (and what it **doesn't**) doe and make sure it fits in with your needs. It is not an exact replacement for Facebook's solution.

If it does seem to meet your needs, you can probably use the PHP API at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ to navigate the OAuth2 process, which is probably the trickiest part of the whole thing. You may also be able to use the Google+ Login button they have described as part of the History API. After that it is a matter of sending an insert command (via an HTTP POST documented at https://developers.google.com/+/history/#writing_moments) and making sure you have a page that has snippet markup information in it to be inserted (documented at https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet and schema.org).

Answer (score 1):

The API of Google+ is read only, sorry.

Comment: So far, the plus interface is completely lame. I can sign in with it, and that's about all it does. Nowhere near as useful as twitter or facebook in that regard. You might be able to Jerry rig something through Curl using php, but Google doesn't like it when people do stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the google-php client, but as pointed above, this client is still in development process. In fact, the latest library is 0.6.1 but is not having all methods required to post. As posted in my question [401 Unauthorized access when posting Google+ Moments with PHP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759821/401-unauthorized-access-when-posting-google-moments-with-php-client), you must download the latest developed library from the SVN repo and then you can check if post momments work with the [Silvano script](https://gist.github.com/silvolu/5054214), after setting both API google console and your library config file.

You can read more things about this issue in the Silvano G+ post: 
https://plus.google.com/+SilvanoLuciani/posts/2kMX9Dzaf8V