# Post in Google+ stream is not showing up in user's stream using google-api-PHP-client

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to post in a user's Google+ stream, and I'm trying it using the google-api PHP client. Until now, I've been able of configure a test environment using the latest google-api PHP client and an example script (See [401 Unauthorized access when posting Google+ Moments with PHP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759821/401-unauthorized-access-when-posting-google-moments-with-php-client) for more information). It looks like it posts, because it returns an array with the answer, but nothing shows up in the user stream.

The answer array is:

```
Array ( 
    [kind] => plus#moment 
    [type] => http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity 
    [target] => Array ( 
        [kind] => plus#itemScope 
        [url] => https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing 
    ) 
    [result] => Array ( 
        [kind] => plus#itemScope 
    ) 
    [id] => xxxxxxxxx 
)
```

which looks correct. Does anyone know why this is happens and how to solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App activities do not render in the user's stream but instead render in the app activities section of Google+ here:

https://plus.google.com/apps/

To prevent spam in the stream, the user must explicitly share to their stream in Google+. You can do this using [Shares](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) and [Interactive Posts](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive).

Comment: Incredible. I've seen all my posts there, :P. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful and it's great to hear you like the feature!

Comment: Hi Class, yeah, your answer was great because explained exactly what I was looking for, but sorry, I'm not glad of watching all the post of my APP in a place where nowhere is going to look into. In fact, to my, as a developer, is going to be a pain to obtain visibility in Google+. When my APP post something I want the users's circle watching it immediately and with no user interaction, because most of the time the user will not go to a place to share a post, and he'll have a lot of APP publishs but no other people will watch it... :_(

Comment: It'd probably be worth it to add a star or feature request in the issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/ if you would like to see a more prominent placement for app activities.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've upvoted issue 41, and commented the same as above there, hope you'll take it in account, :D

Comment: Another way to gain visibility is to create an Interactive Post Share button, which a user must initiate. However, you can pre-fill both the text of the post and up to 10 intended recipients. The user can make changes if they want and then perform the actual share. You can learn more at https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive or by watching this Google+ Developers Live episode: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Iw28jWtAY.